# how can i add button in cell to open link

Tags: xcode, url, uitableview

I want to make a button in cell that will open URL.
I try to make it as always, but it doesn't work.
I have custom cell with it .h/.m files and the tableView inside UIViewController. Where I have put code? and will this code work?

```
- (IBAction)site:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vk.com"]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you just have to connect the button target to this IBAction.
Go to Interface Builter, right click the files owner or app delegate, depends on how you have set it up. Then you should see the site IBAction, just drag it to the button and it should work.

Just add the code to the current view controller.

Comment: what if i want to make it not exact page but tha page url taken from .plist. Do I need to put this somehow in cellforrowatindexpath?

Comment: what? no, you never add actions in a button cell, this is more than wrong. You have to add the IBAction to the controller and connect it via Interface Builder. Check out the basics of cocoa here:
http://cocoadevcentral.com

Comment: how can i open via ibaction different sites with links taken from .plist file?

Comment: as i understand i can set text in temporary NSstring and then to open the same temporary nsstring in IBaction with method URLWithString... Which code I have to use to set value for this temporary string inside cellforrowatindexpath?